# metastore_db created wherever I run Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Folder `metastore_db` is created in any directory where I run Hive query. Is there any way to have only one `metastore_db` in a defined location and stop it from being created all over the places? Does it have anything to do with `hive.metastore.local`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The property of interest here is `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL`. The default value of this property is `jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true`. This value specifies that you will be using embedded derby as your Hive metastore and the location of the metastore is `metastore_db`. Also the metastore will be created if it doesn't already exist.

Note that the location of the metastore (`metastore_db`) is a relative path. Therefore, it gets created where you launch Hive from. If you update this property (in your hive-site.xml) to be, say an absolute path to a location, the metastore will be used from that location.

I must warn you though that embedded derby metastore can only be accessed by one user at a time. Hive uses embedded derby by default to allow an out of the box experience and for ease of testing. For any practical system, I would recommend moving to standalone "real" database like MySQL or PostgreSQL. Instructions on how to do that are available [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_hive_metastore_configure.html).

Comment: any idea how to set also a default location for the generated derby.log?

Comment: I change the path to absolute: ``jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/root/metastore_db;create=true`` but I got the error message: ``java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D``

Comment: @zack the error you have listed might be due to some other property in hive-site.xml file (e.g. hive.exec.local.scratchdir). Am able to get the ConnectionURL working with absolute metastore path. Only issue pending is how to prevent creation of derby.log file in every directory i trigger hive script from.

Comment: Which file does this need to be changed in ?

Comment: Thank you sir Mark!

Answer (score 5):

Since you use Embedded derby mode. To use single metastore_db location. you need to change following properties.

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>  
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/<file-location>/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

I hope this will help you. For more details [click here](http://www.hiregion.com/2010/01/hive-metastore-derby-db.html)

Comment: Seems like the link is down