# FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: hadoop, hql, hive, hdfs

I shutdown my HDFS client while HDFS and hive instances were running. Now when I relogged into Hive, I can't execute any of my DDL Tasks e.g. "show tables" or "describe tablename" etc. It is giving me the error as below

```
ERROR exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(401)) - FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
```

Can anybody suggest what do I need to do to get my metastore_db instantiated without recreating the tables? Otherwise, I have to duplicate the effort of creating the entire database/schema once again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. These are the steps I followed:

1. Go to $HIVE_HOME/bin/metastore_db
2. Copied the db.lck to db.lck1 and dbex.lck to dbex.lck1
3. Deleted the lock entries from db.lck and dbex.lck
4. Log out from hive shell as well as from all running instances of HDFS
5. Re-login to HDFS and hive shell. If you run DDL commands, it may again give you the "Could not instantiate HiveMetaStoreClient error"
6. Now copy back the db.lck1 to db.lck and dbex.lck1 to dbex.lck
7. Log out from all hive shell and HDFS instances
8. Relogin and you should see your old tables

Note: Step 5 may seem a little weird because even after deleting the lock entry, it will still give the HiveMetaStoreClient error but it worked for me.

Advantage: You don't have to duplicate the effort of re-creating the entire database.

Hope this helps somebody facing the same error. Please vote if you find useful. Thanks ahead

Comment: I am not able to connect mysql databases when i using the hive command prompt.. Just let me know where i am doing wrong... I am getting the same exception when  i am trying to connect."failed-error-in-metadata-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org". If you want to specific files then I will shared that

Answer (score 9):

I was told that generally we get this exception if we  the hive console not terminated properly. 
The fix:

Run the jps command, look for "RunJar" process and kill it using 
kill -9  command

Answer (score 1):

See: [getting error in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452861/getting-error-in-hive/18498974#18498974)

Have you copied the jar containing the JDBC driver for your metadata db into Hive's lib dir?

For instance, if you're using MySQL to hold your metadata db, you wll need to copy

mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar into $HIVE_HOME/lib.

This fixed that same error for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by starting the metastore service. Sometimes service might get stopped if your machine is re-booted or went down. You could start the service by running the command:

Login as `$HIVE_USER`

```
nohup hive --service metastore>$HIVE_LOG_DIR/hive.out 2>$HIVE_LOG_DIR/hive.log &
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with hive server and followed the below steps:
1. Go to $HIVE_HOME/bin/metastore_db
2. Copied the db.lck to db.lck1 and dbex.lck to dbex.lck1
3. Deleted the lock entries from db.lck and dbex.lck
4. Relogin from hive shell. It is working
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For instance, I use MySQL to hold metadata db, I copied

mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar into $HIVE_HOME/lib folder

My error resolved

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing the same problem, and figured out that I had both hive-deafult.xml and hive-site.xml(created manually by me),

I moved my hive-site.xml to hive-site.xml-template(as I was not needed this file) then 
started hive, worked fine.

Cheers,
Ajmal

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue and in my case it was while running `hive` command from command line.

I resolved this issue by running [kinit](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/kinit.htm) command as I was using kerberized hive.

```
kinit -kt <your keytab file location> <kerberos principal>
```