# Error while creating table in hive

Tags: hive

I have installed hive using CDH4.1
i want to use MySql for hive metastore,i have edited the hive-site.xml for configuring with mysql and started hive server and metastore
when i was trying to create table in hive it is showing the following error
**FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask**
Can anyone please help?
I have tried to solve using the following post [FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154060/failed-error-in-metadata-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org)

my hive-site.xml is as follows

```
    <property> 
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
     <value>jdbc:hive2://localhost:21050/;auth=noSasl</value>
     <description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
    </property>

     <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
     </property>

   <property>
   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
   <value>hive</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>Newuser123</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
  <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that 
your Database (MySql) which connects to Hive is not started yet. 
to start:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```