# Hive Cli Driver Custom Error

Tags: hive

I want to achieve the hive cli driver。。but error .. help me..
error code content:

2013-12-01 12:03:09,827 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2013-12-01 12:03:10,384 ERROR parse.SemanticAnalyzer (SemanticAnalyzer.java:getMetaData(1323)) - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to fetch table dwa_fc_viccust_word_click_pay_day
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:958)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:892)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1077)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1053)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:441)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1000)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
        at com.rigelci.smartq.hive.Test.processCmd(Test.java:177)
        at com.rigelci.smartq.hive.Test.processLine(Test.java:268)
        at com.rigelci.smartq.hive.Test.execute(Test.java:303)
        at com.rigelci.smartq.hive.Test.main(Test.java:45)

Answer (score 0):

there are actually two different issues here.

1) the first "NativeCodeLoader" is after just a warning that you can safely ignore.  You can find out more about that here   [Hadoop “Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform” error on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos)

2) The "Unable to fetch table" is a real error. There are a couple of items to check - that are also laid out in a separate SOF question here :  [FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154060/failed-error-in-metadata-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org)