# Show databases command not working in hive?

Tags: hive

I connected hive, and when I try to show all databases using command below, I get the following error,:

```
techgene@slaveone:~/apps/hive-0.12.0$ hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/techgene/apps/hive-0.12.0/lib/hive-common-0.12.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties

hive> show databases;

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
```

Can you please provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occurs when hive CLI session is improperly ended. In such case, kill the improperly closed hive CLI session as follows. After this launch hive CLI fresh.

```
ramisetty@aspire:~$ jps
3710 SecondaryNameNode
4103 RunJar -------------------------> hive CLI instance.
4019 TaskTracker
3467 DataNode
3242 NameNode
4366 Jps
3788 JobTracker
ramisetty@aspire:~$ kill -9 4103
ramisetty@aspire:~$
```

still problem persists means follow the available solutions @ [FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154060/failed-error-in-metadata-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org)