# Hive installation issues: Hive metastore database is not initialized

Tags: hadoop, installation, hive, derby

I tried to install hive on a raspberry pi 2. I installed Hive by uncompress zipped Hive package and configure $HADOOP_HOME and $HIVE_HOME manually under hduser user-group I created. When running hive, I got the following error message:
hive

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql)

So I ran the command suggested in the above error message:
schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
I got the error message:

> Error: FUNCTION 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' already exists. (state=X0Y68,code=30000)
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
>   *** schemaTool failed ***

It seems there aren't any helpful information when I try to google this error online. Any help or any explanation on how Hive works with Derby would be appreciated!

Answer (score 146):

After installing hive, if the first thing you did was run hive, hive attempted to create/initialize the metastore_db, but apparently might not get it right. On that initial run, maybe you saw your error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql)
```

Running hive, even though it fails, creates a metastore_db directory in the directory from which you ran hive:

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>ls -l |grep meta
drwxrwxr-x 5 testuser testuser 4096 Apr 14 12:44 metastore_db
```

So when you then tried running

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
```

The metastore already existed, but not in complete form.

Soooooo the answer is:

1. Before you run hive for the first time, run

   schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
2. If you already ran hive and then tried to initSchema and it's failing:

   mv metastore_db metastore_db.tmp
3. Re run

   schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
4. Run hive again

**Also of note: if you change directories, the metastore_db created above won't be found! I'm sure there's a good reason for this that I don't know yet because I'm literally trying to use hive for the first time today. Ahhh here's information on this: metastore_db created wherever I run Hive

Comment: Note that you need to restart derby after deleting or moving metastore_db folder before rerunning schema tool. Otherwise, you will get the same error on rerun.

Comment: Nice explanation. (Not just press that switch and magic will happen)

Comment: O MY GOD, why is this not mentioned in official docs. Thank you!

Comment: @Rebecca were you able to find out how to set the metastore permanently so that we don't create new metastore_db folder everytime invoking from a new directory the hive script.

Comment: For those looking for answer to fix the metastore_db location, look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13651963/5679728

Comment: Note that this problem happens with other databases as well.   If you are using mysql, do: 'drop database metastore; create database metastore' instead of removing a Derby file.

Comment: the "also of note" save my life: If I run `hive` in different directory,  it sometimes works well(After I init schema), but another times, it does not work, because it will auto generate a `metastore_db` which is not properly configured.

Comment: At last I found the reason why inconsistency for run `hive` in different directory, I should use an absolute path: `/an/absolute/path/metastore_db` for derby instead of  relative path: `metastore_db`

Comment: THANKYOU SIR Cole!

Answer (score 19):

I installed hive with HomeBrew(MacOS) at /usr/local/Cellar/hive and afer running
`schematool -dbType derby -initSchema`  I get the following error message:

Starting metastore schema initialization to 2.0.0
Initialization script hive-schema-2.0.0.derby.sql
Error: FUNCTION 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' already exists. (state=X0Y68,code=30000)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!

However, I can't find  either metastore_db or metastore_db.tmp folder under install path, so I tried:

1. `find /usr/ -name hive-schema-2.0.0.derby.sql`
2. `vi /usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.0.1/libexec/scripts/metastore/upgrade/derby/hive-schema-2.0.0.derby.sql`
3. comment the 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' function and 'NUCLEUS_MATCHES' function
4. rerun `schematool -dbType derby -initSchema`, then everything goes well!

hope this help someone.

Comment: this is a great answer. How about using  it to my question over here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947930/unable-to-initialize-hive-with-derby-from-brew-install

Answer (score 16):

I encountered a similar issue, which I fixed by removing the derby database files `rm -Rf $HIVE_HOME/metastore_db`

**Be aware, this will remove your schema completely!**

After cleaning the old schema I could reinitialize with:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
```

It might differ from where you call hive, try to go to your hive installation directory and run `./bin/hive`

Comment: have you any other suggestions I tried this and get the same schema tool failed error as above

Comment: In my case the database is mysql.Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:
schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema

Read the documentation of Hive SchemTool:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool

Answer (score 0):

If you use Derby, you can remove DB files and run the init process.

Or if problem persists, you can edit the SQL files Hive use. For example:

`/usr/hdp/2.5.6.0-40/hive2/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/` contains those for mysql.