# Hive Metastore initialisation

Tags: hive

I am trying to set up metastore for Hive but getting error saying:

> "Hive metastore is not initialized"

I tried it with derby and mysql but I am getting the same error for both the database.

Comment: maybe check out the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655306/hive-installation-issues-hive-metastore-database-is-not-initialized

Comment: Hi I already tried all the solutions provided in stackover flow and other sites but none of them works for me. Do you have an other solution ?

Comment: hi do you have another trick to solve this problem or could you please provide me any better link to re install the hive on my machine ?

Answer (score 1):

For a mysql databasem you first have to create a userhive and a metastore database. You then have to initialize the metastore thought the below command:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool  -dbType mysql  -initSchema
```

This will initialize the schema.

more detail on [that tutorial](https://mapr.com/docs/60/Hive/Config-RemotePostgreSQLForHiveMetastore.html)