# Not able to enter Hive Shell

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, hiveql

I am trying to enter hive shell from cli but its failing by throwing below error:-
I followed exactly this link for the installation :-http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_installation.htm

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
>
> Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true , username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true , username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=trueCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true , username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app).
>
> Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Comment: not sure whether this is the same problem, but check this link. I recently installed hive in ubuntu and  faced the following problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655306/hive-installation-issues-hive-metastore-database-is-not-initialized

Comment: Have you restarted your `terminal` after configuring `.bashrc`. If yes then please share the output of `echo $CLASSPATH` and `ls -l $DERBY_HOME/lib/derbytools.jar` commands.

Comment: Yes I restarted .bashrc. The Output of  echo $CLASSPATH is :/home/ajith/hadoop/lib/*:.:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:.:/usr/local/derby/lib/derby.jar:/usr/local/derby/lib/derbytools.jar And for ls -l $DERBY_HOME/lib/derbytools.jar  ---> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 229665 Sep 20  2015 /usr/local/derby/lib/derbytools.jar

Answer (score 1):

```
Place  sql driver in $HOME/lib folder


change hive-site.xml properties


<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
<description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>



<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive_metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  </property>



<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
 <value>True</value>
 </property>

 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>root</value>
    <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>


 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>root</value>
    <description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you are referring to install the hive is looking quite old (for apache-hive-**0.14.0** which requires a separate derby database).

In place of this, you can try to install apache-hive-**1.2.1** which have in-build derby database and you do not have to install and configure database explicitly.

You can try the steps mentioned in this blog [install-hive-121-on-ubuntu-1404](http://livingforhadoop.blogspot.in/2015/07/install-hive-121-on-ubuntu-1404.html)

Comment: Instead of derby I used MYSQL and the problem was solved Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to start Derby Database before Starting hive server.

1527 port is Derby Port.
While Start hive server,initially it access derby port.

So go to Derby\bin and Type "startNetworkServer"

After give above command 1527 port will listen,
then start the hive metastore and hiveserver2.

Now hive server can able to work correctly.

Sure this more helpful for you