# Hive - Issue on starting derby db

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby

**My Path value is:**

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/hive/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/root/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin

**Exceptions:**

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql))
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql))
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:545)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql))
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql))
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3590)
    ... 16 more
```

Please help me
Many thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655306/hive-installation-issues-hive-metastore-database-is-not-initialized check this one

Comment: The auto-create flag for Derby is to add `;create=true` to the end of your JDBC Connection URL.