# Unable to initialize hive with Derby from Brew install

Tags: hive, derby

It had been my understanding that `Derby` creates file(s) in the current directory. But there are none there.

So I had tried to do the `hive` initialization using `Derby`: but .. it seems there *is* a derby database already.

```
 schematool --verbose -initSchema -dbType derby


Starting metastore schema initialization to 2.1.0
Initialization script hive-schema-2.1.0.derby.sql
Connecting to jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
Connected to: Apache Derby (version 10.10.2.0 - (1582446))
Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver (version 10.10.2.0 - (1582446))
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
0: jdbc:derby:> !autocommit on
Autocommit status: true
0: jdbc:derby:> CREATE FUNCTION "APP"."NUCLEUS_ASCII" (C CHAR(1)) RETURNS INTEGER LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA READS SQL DATA CALLED ON NULL INPUT EXTERNAL NAME 'org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.adapter.DerbySQLFunction.ascii'
Error: FUNCTION 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' already exists. (state=X0Y68,code=30000)

Closing: 0: jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
Underlying cause: java.io.IOException : Schema script failed, errorcode 2
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:291)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:264)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:505)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Schema script failed, errorcode 2
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.runBeeLine(HiveSchemaTool.java:390)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.runBeeLine(HiveSchemaTool.java:347)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:287)
```

So .. where is it?

**Update**  I have *reinstalled hive from scratch*  using

```
  brew reinstall hive
```

And the same error occurs.

**Another update**  Given the new direction of this error it now is answered by within another question:

An answer to a non-os/x - but similar otherwise - question was found that can serve here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40017753/1056563

```
I installed hive with HomeBrew(MacOS) at /usr/local/Cellar/hive and afer running schematool -dbType derby -initSchema I get the following error message:

Starting metastore schema initialization to 2.0.0 Initialization script hive-schema-2.0.0.derby.sql Error: FUNCTION 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' already exists. (state=X0Y68,code=30000) org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!

However, I can't find either metastore_db or metastore_db.tmp folder under install path, so I tried:

find /usr/ -name hive-schema-2.0.0.derby.sql
vi /usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.0.1/libexec/scripts/metastore/upgrade/derby/hive-schema-2.0.0.derby.sql
comment the 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' function and 'NUCLEUS_MATCHES' function
rerun schematool -dbType derby -initSchema, then everything goes well!
```

Comment: You might have to look at the hive configuration file. That should tell you where it is being initialized.

Comment: ah ya.. been a while for doing hive.  you can make that an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Homebrew installs Hive (version 2.3.1) unconfigured. The default settings are to use in-process Derby database (Hive already includes the required lib).

The only thing you have to do (**immediatelly** after `brew install hive`) is to initialize the database:

```
schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
```

and then you can run `hive`, and it will work. However, if you tried to run `hive` before initializing the database, Hive will actually semi-create an incomplete database and will fail to work:

```
show tables;
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Since the database is semi-created, `schematool` will now fail as well:

```
Error: FUNCTION 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' already exists. (state=X0Y68,code=30000)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
```

To fix that, you will have to delete the database:

```
rm -Rf metastore_db
```

and run the initilization command again.

Noticed that I deleted the metastore_db from current directory? This is another problem: Hive is configured to create and use the Derby database in current working dir. This is because it has the following default value for ‘javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL’:

```
jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
```

To fix that, create file `/usr/local/opt/hive/libexec/conf/hive-site.xml` as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:derby:/usr/local/var/hive/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

and recreate the database like before. Now the database is in `/usr/local/var/hive`, so in case you again accidentally ran `hive` before initializing the DB, delete it with:

```
rm -Rf /usr/local/var/hive
```

Comment: Excellent solution - this should be upvoted and added to the brew install docs for hive

Comment: For those who doesn't know where is the file `metastore_db` located, use GNU find to search it: `find / -name "metastore_db"` :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have to look at the hive configuration file. That should tell you where it is being initialized.

Comment: so ***actually*** .. I reinstalled hive from scratch - which means there are no config files even available (only the `.template`).  And the above error *still* occurs. Any further thoughts?

Comment: @javadba Could it be connecting to an in memory database? Then once the transaction is complete it dumps to disk.

Comment: Not an answer. What file? Where? What parameter?