# Hadoop Metastore Will Not Initialize

Tags: hive, derby, metastore

preamble:  i'm new to hadoop / hive.  have installed standalone hadoop and now am trying to get hive to work.  i keep getting an error about initializing the metastore and cannot seem to figure out how to resolve.   (hadoop 2.7.2 and hive 2.0)

HADOOP_HOME AND HIVE_HOME ARE SET

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>echo $HADOOP_HOME
/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2

ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>echo $HIVE_HOME
/usr/hive
```

hdfs is working

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>hadoop fs -ls /
Found 2 items
drwxrwxr-x   - testuser supergroup          0 2016-04-13 21:37 /tmp
drwxrwxr-x   - testuser supergroup          0 2016-04-13 21:38 /user

ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>hadoop fs -ls /user
Found 1 items
drwxrwxr-x   - testuser supergroup          0 2016-04-13 21:38 /user/hive

ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>hadoop fs -ls /user/hive
Found 1 items
drwxrwxr-x   - testuser supergroup          0 2016-04-13 21:38 /user/hive/warehouse

ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>groups
testuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

hive is not working.  says i need to initialize my metastore

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>hive

Logging initialized using configuration in
jar:file:/usr/hive/lib/hive-common-2.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive metastore database
is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema
-dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the 
option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string
(e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql)
```

so i try to initialize it useing postgres - but schematool tries to use derby

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>schematool -initSchema -dbType postgres
Metastore connection URL:  jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
Metastore Connection Driver :  org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Metastore connection User:   APP
Starting metastore schema initialization to 2.0.0
Initialization script hive-schema-2.0.0.postgres.sql
Error: Syntax error: Encountered "statement_timeout" at line 1, column 5.
(state=42X01,code=30000)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization
FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

so i change hive-site.xml to use postgres drivers etc.  but because i don't
have the drivers installed, it fails

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>cp /usr/hive/conf/hive-site.xml.templ /usr/hive/conf/hive-site.xml
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>schematool -initSchema -dbType postgres
Metastore connection URL:  jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hivedb
Metastore Connection Driver :  org.postgresql.Driver
Metastore connection User:   123456
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to load driver
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

so then i try to use derby
first move the hive-site.xml out of the way again so default is derby

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>mv /usr/hive/conf/hive-site.xml /usr/hive/conf/hive-site.xml.templ
```

then i try intializing again with derby but it appears to already be
initialized per the error "Error:  FUNCTION 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' already exists"

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
Metastore connection URL:  jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
Metastore Connection Driver :  org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Metastore connection User:   APP
Starting metastore schema initialization to 2.0.0
Initialization script hive-schema-2.0.0.derby.sql
Error: FUNCTION 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' already exists. (state=X0Y68,code=30000)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization
FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

I've been at this for two days.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So..

Here's what happened.

After installing hive, the first thing I did was run hive, which attempted to create/initialize the metastore_db, but apparently didn't get it right. On that initial run, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql)
```

Running hive, even though it failed, created a metastore_db directory in the directory from which I ran hive:

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>ls -l |grep meta
drwxrwxr-x 5 testuser testuser 4096 Apr 14 12:44 metastore_db
```

So when I then tried running

```
ubuntu15-laptop: ~ $>schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
```

The metastore already existed, but not in complete form.

Soooooo the answer is:

1. Before you run hive for the first time, run

   schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
2. If you already ran hive and then tried to initSchema and it's failing:

   mv metastore_db metastore_db.tmp
3. Re run

   schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
4. Run hive again

**Also of note:  if you change directories, the metastore_db created above won't be found!  I'm sure there's a good reason for this that I don't know yet because I'm literally trying to use hive for the first time today.  Ahhh here's information on this:  [metastore_db created wherever I run Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624893/metastore-db-created-wherever-i-run-hive)

Comment: Also if you make a change to javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL in hive-site.xml, metastore_db appears in your specified directory, not in $HIVE_HOME.

Comment: Rebecca, you have raised question with postgresql, but in answer seems you have got comfort with Derby. With postgresql were you be able to use schematool?

Comment: It is a good way for this problem. In My Mac 10.12.2, I install hive by brew, get a lot of problem. mv metastore_db metastore_db.tmp;schematool -initSchema -dbType derby;hive; is a great way to solve