# CentOS6.8, Hive:Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I was trying to build spark environment on **CentOS6.8** on **macOS** using **VMware Fusion**.

I have previously installed **jdk-10.0.1**, **hadoop-2.4.1.tar.gz**, and **MySQL**. They worked successfully.

However, when I finished installing **apache-hive-0.13.1-bin.tar.gz**, I received the following as I entered "hive":

```
`Logging initialized using configuration in file:/usr/local/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.4.1.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: The java type java.lang.Integer (jdbc-type="", sql-type="") cant be mapped for this datastore. No mapping is available.
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: The java type java.lang.Integer (jdbc-type="", sql-type="") cant be mapped for this datastore. No mapping is available.
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:591)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:788)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:339)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:397)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4944)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: The java type java.lang.Integer (jdbc-type="", sql-type="") cant be mapped for this datastore. No mapping is available.
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.RDBMSMappingManager.getDatastoreMappingClass(RDBMSMappingManager.java:1215)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.RDBMSMappingManager.createDatastoreMapping(RDBMSMappingManager.java:1378)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.ProbeTable.initialize(ProbeTable.java:66)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.initialiseSchema(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1430)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:391)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
        ... 46 more
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the default derby database? And it seems like you're using it in embedded mode. Right? pls confirm it.

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. I checked my configuration file "hive-site.xml". The followings are related configurations about derby:

Comment: <property>
  <name>hive.stats.jdbcdriver</name>
  <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
  <description>The JDBC driver for the database that stores temporary Hive statistics.</description>
</property>                                                                                                   <property>
  <name>hive.stats.dbconnectionstring</name>
 <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=TempStatsStore;create=true</value>
  <description>The default connection string for the database that stores temporary Hive statistics.</description>
</property>

Comment: Okay. So your default database for hive is Derby as mentioned in the configuration. So, the problem is that you have to install Hive with mysql because you have written in your question that you have installed mysql on your machine earlier and it was succesful so you can not have two types of databases for hive. Either install hive with default DB in another node or if you have single node cluster then configure hive with mysql

Comment: Here is a link for you. This may be of some help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711364/java-lang-runtimeexceptionunable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-metastor

Comment: I am sorry but I can't find where the folder "metastore_db" is. There is no such folder under "hive". And I also can't find it under /usr/ directory

Comment: Metastore_db has a relative path. It exists where you run hive command. You can look for the path in hive-site.xml. For more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624893/metastore-db-created-wherever-i-run-hive